# Argumentos dentro de una función en Javascript

Tags: javascript, web

Estimados buenas tardes!

Actualmente estoy estudiando programación en Javascript por mi cuenta y me surge la siguiente duda un amigo armo una funcion la cual al hacer click en una etiqueta anchor aparece un texto y al volver a cliquear en el anchor desaparece. 
En si la funcion la entiendo pero al pasar los parametros dentro de la funcion hay un ID que me hace ruido ya que no se supone que el ID es unico osea en el script de abajo asigna valor a una variable x con un document.getElementById(bloque) pero los id de los parrafos a mostrar son bloque1, bloque 2, bloque 3 ??

Codigo HTML;

```
<div id="ej2">
    <h2>Ejercicio 2</h2>

    <div id="botonera">
        <h4>Mostrar/Ocultar</h4>
        <button class="botones" onclick="cambiarVisibilidad('bloque1')">BLOQUE 1</button>
        <button class="botones" onclick="cambiarVisibilidad('bloque2')" href="">BLOQUE 2</button>
        <button class="botones" onclick="cambiarVisibilidad('bloque3')" href="">BLOQUE 3</button>
    </div>

    <p id="bloque1">
        1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In adipisci officiis maiores. Adipisci quas
        commodi eum iure optio, tempore est quae architecto dicta qui. Quisquam optio similique iure nobis.
        Voluptatem, totam sint nihil iusto quisquam excepturi fugit placeat sunt in dolorum ratione nobis culpa
        repellat libero animi, accusamus recusandae velit.
    </p>
```

#Script#

```
function cambiarVisibilidad(bloque) {
    var bloque = document.getElementById(bloque);

    if (bloque.style.display == "none"){
        bloque.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        bloque.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Muchas Gracias y Saludos!!

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el argumento `bloque` que recibe la función `cambiarVisibilidad` contiene el id del parrafo, así lo hace más dinamico y no tiene que hacer una función por cada uno de los parrafos

Answer (score 0):

Para que tu codigo funcione no necesitas el `href`.  Ademas de la forma que lo tienes, si necesitarias tres parrafos con ids bloque1, bloque2y bloque3.

```js
function cambiarVisibilidad(bloque) {
    var bloque = document.getElementById(bloque);

    if (bloque.style.display == "none"){
        bloque.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        bloque.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="ej2">
    <h2>Ejercicio 2</h2>

    <div id="botonera">
        <h4>Mostrar/Ocultar</h4>
        <button class="botones" onclick="cambiarVisibilidad('bloque1')">BLOQUE 1</button>
        <button class="botones" onclick="cambiarVisibilidad('bloque2')">BLOQUE 2</button>
        <button class="botones" onclick="cambiarVisibilidad('bloque3')">BLOQUE 3</button>
    </div>

    <p id="bloque1">
        1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In adipisci officiis maiores. Adipisci quas
        commodi eum iure optio, tempore est quae architecto dicta qui. Quisquam optio similique iure nobis.
        Voluptatem, totam sint nihil iusto quisquam excepturi fugit placeat sunt in dolorum ratione nobis culpa
        repellat libero animi, accusamus recusandae velit.</p>
    <p id="bloque2">
        2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In adipisci officiis maiores. Adipisci quas
        commodi eum iure optio, tempore est quae architecto dicta qui. Quisquam optio similique iure nobis.
        Voluptatem, totam sint nihil iusto quisquam excepturi fugit placeat sunt in dolorum ratione nobis culpa
        repellat libero animi, accusamus recusandae velit.</p>
    <p id="bloque3">
        3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In adipisci officiis maiores. Adipisci quas
        commodi eum iure optio, tempore est quae architecto dicta qui. Quisquam optio similique iure nobis.
        Voluptatem, totam sint nihil iusto quisquam excepturi fugit placeat sunt in dolorum ratione nobis culpa
        repellat libero animi, accusamus recusandae velit.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que éste es tu ejemplo. Cuando se manda a llamar la función **cambiarVisibilidad()** como parámetro se envía bloque1, bloque2 o bloque3 mediante **onclick**, lo que **getElementByID()** hace es buscar un elemento del DOM mediante el parámetro que indicas dentro de la función **cambiarVisibilidad()**. En tu caso cambiarVisibilidad('**bloque1**'), cambiarVisibilidad('**bloque2**') y cambiarVisibilidad('**bloque3**') esos serían los ID para **getElementByID()**.

```js
function cambiarVisibilidad(bloque) {
    var bloque = document.getElementById(bloque);

    if (bloque.style.display == "none"){
        bloque.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        bloque.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="ej2">
    <h2>Ejercicio 2</h2>

    <div id="botonera">
        <h4>Mostrar/Ocultar</h4>
        <button class="botones" onclick="cambiarVisibilidad('bloque1')">BLOQUE 1</button>
        <button class="botones" onclick="cambiarVisibilidad('bloque2')" href="">BLOQUE 2</button>
        <button class="botones" onclick="cambiarVisibilidad('bloque3')" href="">BLOQUE 3</button>
    </div>

    <p id="bloque1" style= "display: none"> 1) contenido 1.</p>
     <p id="bloque2" style= "display: none"> 1) contenido 2.</p>
      <p id="bloque3" style= "display: none"> 1) contenido 3.</p>
```

Comment: OK, aver si lo entendi, dentro de la funcion myFuncion (argumento) var a = document.getElementBy(argumento) deben tener el mismo nombre, pero en el HTML en el onclick=myFuncion('parrafo1'). ya que lo que hace el document.getElementById es buscar dentro del DOM es buscar un parametro que se indica dentro de Myfunction() cuando ejecutamos el onclick.. Muchas gracias por la ayuda, Saludos

Comment: Así mismo, irá buscando lo que le indiques. Por ejemplo, onclick=myFuncion('parrafo1')...  document.getElementBy(argumento) resultará como  **document.getElementBy('parrafo1')**